# I am having trouble in passing a specific image in my template from Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Models.py

```
class BaseLogo(models.Model):
logolabel = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = False, blank = False)
logoimage = models.ImageField(null = False, blank = False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.logolabel
```

Views.py

```
def base(request):

baselogo = get_object_or_404(BaseLogo, pk=1)
context = {
  'baselogo': baselogo,
 }

return render(request, 'pages/base.html', context)
```

Settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS= [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/flababu/VCASite/staticfiles/'



MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Template

```
<a class="nav-brand" href="{% url 'main-home' %}">
  <img src="{{ baselogo.logoimage.url }}" alt="VCAAT Logo" title="VCAAT Logo"
  style="width: 60px; height: 60px; float: left; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px;"></a>
```

Notes:

1. It is in NavBar
2. I have a gallery app and I also have profile pictures, so I was able to pass images before.
3. The website is uploaded in pythonanywhere.
4. I have an image uploaded in admin page

I don't understand what is wrong why my image (logo) would not appear.

Comment: Django does not serve media files in production, because it is likely unsafe, and inefficient. You need to configure nginx/apache/... to serve the media/static files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right with my hunch that views.py was not the answer/ the problem at all. I remove my base in views.py. I created a new file custom_context_processor

**custom_context_processor.py**

```
from .models import BaseLogo


def base_renderer(request):

  baselogo = BaseLogo.objects.first()
  context = {
    'baselogo': baselogo,
   }


  return context
```

And then added it to my

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'pages.custom_context_processor.base_renderer',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

And its now running as intended, as it turned out, this is very common practice, Thank you for those who tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

in your settings.py add this 2 lines

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

media root is for telling your project where to put media files, and media url is for telling django to use this folder (link) for links (urls) so you can use it on your project and show images, if you don't tell django the media url, you are unable to show images from media files

Update:

then try this one, this code is for my project, it's very similar to what you want

in models.py in your model class

```
profileimage = ImageField(default="default.jpg", upload_to=your_desire_folder_path, blank=True)
```

you can give it any name you want, it is not related to media folder

Comment: I already have them is my settings.py, I'll add it above

Comment: I tried it, still the same, I also had that in my User App, and its working fine, I don't know why it wont work for this one, Thanks for trying to help me! thanks a lot

Comment: well, I'm thinking to how to solve this, try this one for me see if it's work
baselogo = BaseLogo.objects.all()
try it with pk=1 and without pk=1
I'm still looking to solve this

Comment: did you add       + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) in your main urls.py?

Comment: Yes i already have that in my main urls.py, I do have a hunch tho, I think it is because my base.html does not really have a page on its own, I only use my base.html so that my other pages can inherit it because it has my nav bar, background and footer. Maybe I should not use Views.py for this one, but im not sure

Comment: it is not related to your base.html file, I can't guess anything else, last thing i could say is to check the entire code and files, make sure indents are correct

Comment: by the way, you didn't pass 'DIRS': [], in templates settings.py try that